# Объясните как работает верификация в ssh на пальцах

Tags: безопасность, ssh, шифрование

Прочитал несколько разных источников но так и не понял.

Говориться о том что сначала мы сгеренировали секретный ключ симметричный на основе алгоритма Диффи-Хеллмана, потом получили его хеш и его отправили, а сервер его сверил и т.п. Но я так и не понял как это работает с атакой "человек по середине".

Т.е. допустим что кто-то полностью перехватывает мой трафик и отправляет со свой стороны генерацию ключей на сервер, и ключ он получил и хеш он него будет корректный т.к. он будет с сервером так же его генерировать с нуля по алгоритмы, а я отправлю пароль защифрованный ключем который мы с этим злоумышленником создадим для канала между собой, и соответственно он его благополучно расшифрует.

В нескольких источниках упоминалась некая "верификация" что я это я и сервер это сервер но я так и не понял как она работает...

Comment: В принципе на ssh атака mitm может иметь место. Для борьбы с этим при первом подключении к какому нибудь серверу ssh сохраняет хеш его ключа у себя (для *nix систем в ~/.ssh/known_hosts) и при всех последующих подключениях проверяет, если ключ вдруг изменится, то ssh выдаст вам предупреждение и вы можете сами решить продолжать подключение или отказаться

Comment: 1) Т.е. ключ всегда один при последующих подключения?
2) А если первое же подключение подвергается атаке?

Comment: 1. Да, rsa ключ у сервера всегда один. Ключ шифрования сессии конечно разный. 2. Если mitm на первом подключении - значит не повезло